# Show hide created html in jquery based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I have a page where the user selects a checkbox, based on the checkbox I perform an ajax call and get 'modules' returned. These are a varying amount, from 0 to 10 or more. The thing is that the modules show up in the second step of my website, which is disabled until the first step (the checking of a checkbox) is done.

I have a text in step 2 saying "Select a package in step 1 first before modules show up".

The way I want it to work is:
If the user comes on the page for the first time and checks a checkbox, the text in the second step fades out and the modules (retrieved via ajax and html created in jQuery) fade in slowly. After changing another package in step 1, I want the currently shown modules to fade out, and the new ones to fade in again.

I know where my code goes wrong (when I keep calling the same showModules(data) function, but I do not know how to fix it.

My HTML looks like this:

```
            <h3>Stap 1: Kies een lidmaatschap</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                $columnsize = floor((12 /  count($allpackages)));
                foreach ($allpackages as $package) {
                    echo "<div class='col-md-$columnsize'>";
                    echo "<h4>$package->name</h4>";
                    echo "<p>$package->short_description</p>";
                    echo "<p>De volgende modules zitten in het pakket:</p>";
                    echo "<p><ul>";
                    foreach ($package->modules as $module) {
                        echo "<li>$module->name</li>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul></p>";
                    echo "<p>Prijs: $package->price_eur €/jaar + $package->suborg_price_eur €/jaar per deelorganisatie</p>";
                    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"package\" class=\"radiobtnpackage\" value='$package->package_id' required>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <h3>Stap 2: Kies extra modules (optioneel)</h3>
            <div class="modulegrid">
                <p class="packagestep2fadeout">Selecteer eerst een pakket voor de overige beschikbare modules te bekijken.</p>
                <div class="moduleholder" style="display: none;">aaaaaaa</div>
            </div>
```

The jQuery looks like this:

```
var packageSelected = false;
    $('input[name=package]').change(function(ev){
        var ajaxPackageOptions = {
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseUrl + 'pricing/modules/getModuleById',
            dataType: 'json'
        };

        var packageData = {
            "packageid": $( 'input[name=package]:checked' ).val()
        };

        var optionsPackages = $.extend({}, ajaxPackageOptions, {
            data: packageData
        });

        ev.preventDefault();

        // ajax done & fail
        $.ajax(optionsPackages).done(function (data) {
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(data.result)) {
                //console.log(data.result);
                //console.log(packageSelected);
                showModules(data);
                if (packageSelected) {
                    $( ".moduleholder" ).fadeOut( 1000, function() {
                        showModules(data.result);
                        $( ".moduleholder" ).fadeIn( 2500, function() {

                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    //First time a package is selected we need to fade out the first text
                    $( ".packagestep2fadeout" ).fadeOut( 1000).promise().done(function() {
                        // Animation complete.
                        packageSelected = true;
                        showModules(data);
                        $( ".moduleholder" ).fadeIn( 2500, function() {

                        });
                    });
                }
            } else {
                //Geen modules beschikbaar tonen
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
            //TODO: show error notification
            //alert('TODO: show error notification');
        });
    });

    function showModules(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        var container = $('<div class="modulename" />');
        $.each( data.result, function( key, value ) {
            container.append($("<h2>"+value['name']+"</h2>"));
        });
        $('.moduleholder').html(container);
    }
```

Everytime the checkbox is changed, the text from the previous modules is immediately replaced by the text from the new ones, before fading out and not in again.

**EDIT**: created a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/146768/)!

Comment: please consider providing a snippet/fiddle so we can more easily reproduce the scenario, also a sample html without php code would help instead

Comment: so according to your fiddle, the problem is the numbers change first and then fade out and then fade in. what you want is them to fade out first then fade in, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely small glitches in your logic, all you needed to do was uncomment next line:

```
    // Animation complete.
    packageSelected = true;

    showModules(a); //<--THIS LINE
    $(".moduleholder").fadeIn(2500, function() {

    });
```

and change

```
showModules(a);
if (packageSelected) {
  $(".moduleholder").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    //showModules(data.result);

    $(".moduleholder").fadeIn(2500, function() {

    });
  });
}
```

for

```
if (packageSelected) {
  $(".moduleholder").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    //showModules(data.result);
    showModules(a);
    $(".moduleholder").fadeIn(2500, function() {

    });
  });
}
```

[check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/146970/)

HIH

Comment: I was so close but just couldn't get my head around it! Thanks, works great!

Answer (score 1):

It changes immediately because your data is already set and visible when you create it with `showModules()`. You should `.hide()` the data after you create it with `showModules()`. Then it'll `fadeIn()` nicely since it's `.hidden()` before you `fadeIn()`. Take a look at the example below.

**Edit:** Ok, so I was right in what's going wrong, but I was wrong in the placement of `.hide()`. Commenting out `$(".moduleholder").hide();`  in the `else` statement reproduces what you were talking about. I've moved it to the `else` statement. I've also removed the `.promise()` of your `$( ".packagestep2fadeout" ).fadeOut()` call.

```js
var packageSelected = false;
$('input[name=package]').change(function(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/justinjmnz",
  }).done(function(data) {
    var div = $(".moduleholder");
    if (packageSelected) {
      div.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        showModules(data);
        // div.hide(); // Hide the data so it fades in nice: EDIT: Don't really need it here
        div.fadeIn(2500);
      });
    } else {
      $(".packagestep2fadeout").fadeOut(1000, function() { // Removed .promise()
        packageSelected = true;
        showModules(data);
        $(".moduleholder").hide(); // It's supposed to be here
        $(".moduleholder").fadeIn(2500);
      });
    }
  });
});

function showModules(data) {
  var container = $('<div class="modulename" />');
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    // console.log(key, value);
    container.append($("<p>Key: " + key + "</br>Value: " + value + "</p>"));
  });
  // Surprise at the bottom!
  container.append($("<img src=" + data.avatar_url + "</img>"));
  $('.moduleholder').html(container);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="package">
<p class="packagestep2fadeout">Selecteer eerst een pakket voor de overige beschikbare modules te bekijken.</p>
<div class="moduleholder">
</div>
```

In your example it'll look something like this:

```
 $(".packagestep2fadeout").fadeOut(1000, function() { // Removed .promise()
    packageSelected = true;
    showModules(data);
    $(".moduleholder").hide(); // Added this guy
    $(".moduleholder").fadeIn(2500);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should illustrate what you are trying to do. It's all about the placement of the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` calls.

```js
var details = {
    1: [{name: 'Stuff'}, {name: 'More Stuff'}],
    2: [{name: 'Foo'}, {name: 'Bar'}],
    3: [{name: 'Cheese'}, {name: 'Whine'}],
    4: [{name: 'Ball'}, {name: 'Bat'}]
}

$('input[name=package]').change(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);

  $('.moduleholder').fadeOut(1000); // make sure we "fadeout" on change
  
  // simulate ajax call
    setTimeout(function() {
      var data = {};
      data.result = details[$this.val()];
      showModules(data);
  }, 1000);
});

function showModules(data) {
    var container = $('<div class="modulename" />');
    $.each( data.result, function( key, value ) {
        container.append($("<h2>"+value['name']+"</h2>"));
    });
    $('.moduleholder').html(container);
    $('.moduleholder').fadeIn(1000); // <--- add this here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="package1">Package 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="package" value="1" id="package1"/>
<label for="package2">Package 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="package" value="2" id="package2"/>
<label for="package3">Package 3</label>
<input type="radio" name="package" value="3" id="package3"/>
<label for="package4">Package 4</label>
<input type="radio" name="package" value="4" id="package4"/>

<div>
  <p>Details of selected package</p>
  <div class="moduleholder" style="display: none; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</div>
```